# How to report a numerical result?

Tags: conventions, error-analysis

There is a problem of measurement of speed of sound in steel. It is given that the speed of sound in air is 343 m/s and the length of the steel rod is 100 m. The difference in time for the sound to travel 100 m for air and steel is measured as 0.27 s using an accurate timer.

The way to solve this is clear.

Find the time taken by sound in air to travel 100 m and subtract the time delay from it, which gives the time taken by sound to travel 100m in steel. Divide the length of the rod (100m) by the time found in previous step.

The problem: time taken by sound in air to travel 100 m = 100/343=0.291545. We need to take it to two significant figures, because 0.27 s is given to two sf. Or, we can take it to one extra s.f. since it's an intermediate result. So, t in air is either taken as 0.292 or 0.29. Taking 0.292 the answer comes to 4545 m/s and taking  0.29 gives 5000 m/s.

Also, if we solve algebraically and substitute in the final expression $ t= \frac{100}{\frac{100}{343}-0.27} $ we get 4641 m/s.

Considering the large difference in answers, for the same measured value, which is the best way to give the answer?

Comment: More on [significant figures](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+significant+figures).

Answer (score 1):

If done properly both your methods should yield the similar numerical values which should the be appropriately rounded.

When doing the calculations towards an answer any rounding should not be too severe.  Indeed if done a calculator the use of the memory keys will often require no rounding to be done until the end.
If you wish to round values then look at the values which have presented to you and select the value which is quoted to the least number of significant figures.

In you example the value $343$ is quoted to three significant figures.
The $100$ is more problematic as it could be the value is to one, two or three significant figures but, given the benefit of the doubt, assume three significant figures.
Thus you are left with $0.27$ which is to two significant figures.
In this example to reduce any [rounding errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error) it is best to work with  either four or five significant figures.
You did not do that and this resulted in what looks like a great discrepancy between your two values.

However there is another problems which arises in your computation.
You will note that you have to subtract $0.27$ from a value to which, when noting the potential error in its value, is very nearly equal, $\frac{100}{343}\approx 0.2915$ and this will result in [loss of significance](http://www.zipcon.net/%7Eswhite/docs/math/loss_of_significance.html).
The result of the subtraction gives a value, $0.0215$, which is much smaller than the originating numbers, and given the error in $0.27$, really only correct to 0ne (two at a pinch) significant figures.

Thus given the rounding error in your first calculation and the realization that two approximately equal values are being subtracted from one another, $5000$ to one significant figure is not a bad estimate, and possibly? $4600$.

In your example there is a dominant error in one of the values and it is compounded by a loss in significance due to a subtraction in the denominator of your fraction.

Answer (score 1):

If I want to obtain a rough estimate, I used the **result** and changed the input values to their extreme. I never round intermediate results, because the end result will depend on my  *subjective method* of solving the problem. E.g. if I do not realise that some calculations cancel each another, e.g. $\sqrt{x^2} = x$ or $\log(\exp(x)) = x$, the end result might suffer from the rounding in the intermediate steps.

Using the extrem values in the end result provides the *range* of the data. However, often it is simple to use a simulation to obtain the a distribution of the end result. E.g. here I draw random numbers from uniform distributions for each input parameter. This would also be done in Excel, as long as the math does not become too complicated.

```
nSim = 2e3 # number of simulations

## Input parameters:
v_air = 343 + runif(nSim, -0.5, 0.5)    # [in m/s]
s     = 100 + runif(nSim, -0.5, 0.5)    # [in m]
dt    = 0.27 + runif(nSim, -0.005, 0.005)   # [in s]

## Do the calculation:
# dt = t_air - t_steel 
# => t_steel = ...
t_air   = s/v_air       # time needed in air
t_steel = t_air - dt    # velocity in steel
v_steel = s / t_steel

## Plot:
hist(v_steel)
# add average value to the plot:
abline(v = mean(v_steel), col="red", lwd=5)
# calc quantiles and add them to the plot
q = quantile(v_steel, probs=c(25, 50, 75)*1e-2 )
abline(v = q, lwd = 3)
```

This yields the plot

[image]

The values you reported are all included in the histogram. However, by plotting the histogram we obtain a rather good intuition about probable and rare result. Usually, this is much more valuable than stating only the average value, and a standard deviation.